# How to format columns in pandas using groupby.agg function

Tags: pandas, group-by

I have the following type of table in excel with huge data in it. The data shown below is a simple sample from the large dataset spanning multiple files.

| Time | class | Mode | Value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10/1/22 10:33:31 | 1 | Hot | 200 |
| 10/1/22 10:33:32 | 1 | Hot | 201 |
| 10/1/22 10:33:33 | 1 | Hot | 200 |
| 10/1/22 10:33:34 | 1 | Hot | 200 |
| 10/1/22 10:33:35 | 1 | Cold | 140 |
| 10/1/22 10:33:36 | 1 | Cold | 130 |
| 10/1/22 10:33:37 | 1 | Cold | 140 |
| 10/1/22 10:33:38 | 1 | Cold | 130 |
| 10/1/22 10:33:39 | 1 | Off | 90 |
| 10/1/22 10:33:40 | 1 | Off | 91 |
| 10/1/22 10:33:41 | 1 | Off | 92 |
| 10/1/22 10:33:42 | 1 | Off | 93 |
| 10/1/22 10:33:43 | 2 | Hot | 200 |
| 10/1/22 10:33:44 | 2 | Hot | 201 |
| 10/1/22 10:33:45 | 2 | Hot | 200 |
| 10/1/22 10:33:46 | 2 | Hot | 200 |
| 10/1/22 10:33:47 | 2 | Cold | 140 |
| 10/1/22 10:33:48 | 2 | Cold | 130 |
| 10/1/22 10:33:49 | 2 | Cold | 140 |
| 10/1/22 10:33:50 | 2 | Cold | 130 |
| 10/1/22 10:33:51 | 2 | Off | 90 |
| 10/1/22 10:33:52 | 2 | Off | 91 |
| 10/1/22 10:33:53 | 2 | Off | 92 |
| 10/1/22 10:33:54 | 2 | Off | 93 |
| 10/1/22 10:33:55 | 3 | Hot | 200 |
| 10/1/22 10:33:56 | 3 | Hot | 201 |
| 10/1/22 10:33:57 | 3 | Hot | 200 |
| 10/1/22 10:33:58 | 3 | Hot | 200 |
| 10/1/22 10:33:59 | 3 | Cold | 140 |
| 10/1/22 10:34:00 | 3 | Cold | 130 |
| 10/1/22 10:34:01 | 3 | Cold | 140 |
| 10/1/22 10:34:02 | 3 | Cold | 130 |
| 10/1/22 10:34:03 | 3 | Off | 90 |
| 10/1/22 10:34:04 | 3 | Off | 91 |
| 10/1/22 10:34:05 | 3 | Off | 92 |
| 10/1/22 10:34:06 | 3 | Off | 93 |

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({
    "time": [
        "10/1/22 10:33:31", 
        "10/1/22 10:33:32", 
        "10/1/22 10:33:33", 
        "10/1/22 10:33:34", 
        "10/1/22 10:33:35", 
        "10/1/22 10:33:36", 
        "10/1/22 10:33:37", 
        "10/1/22 10:33:38", 
        "10/1/22 10:33:39", 
        "10/1/22 10:33:40", 
        "10/1/22 10:33:41", 
        "10/1/22 10:33:42", 
        "10/1/22 10:33:43", 
        "10/1/22 10:33:44", 
        "10/1/22 10:33:45", 
        "10/1/22 10:33:46", 
        "10/1/22 10:33:47", 
        "10/1/22 10:33:48", 
        "10/1/22 10:33:49", 
        "10/1/22 10:33:50", 
        "10/1/22 10:33:51", 
        "10/1/22 10:33:52", 
        "10/1/22 10:33:53", 
        "10/1/22 10:33:54", 
        "10/1/22 10:33:55", 
        "10/1/22 10:33:56", 
        "10/1/22 10:33:57", 
        "10/1/22 10:33:58", 
        "10/1/22 10:33:59", 
        "10/1/22 10:34:00", 
        "10/1/22 10:34:01", 
        "10/1/22 10:34:02", 
        "10/1/22 10:34:03", 
        "10/1/22 10:34:04", 
        "10/1/22 10:34:05", 
        "10/1/22 10:34:06"
                ],

    "class": [
        "1",
        "1",
        "1",
        "1",
        "1",
        "1",
        "1",
        "1",
        "1",
        "1",
        "1",
        "1",
        "2",
        "2",
        "2",
        "2",
        "2",
        "2",
        "2",
        "2",
        "2",
        "2",
        "2",
        "2",
        "3",
        "3",
        "3",
        "3",
        "3",
        "3",
        "3",
        "3",
        "3",
        "3",
        "3",
        "3"
    ],
    "mode" : [
        "Hot",
        "Hot",
        "Hot",
        "Hot",
        "Cold",
        "Cold",
        "Cold",
        "Cold",
        "Off",
        "Off",
        "Off",
        "Off",
        "Hot",
        "Hot",
        "Hot",
        "Hot",
        "Cold",
        "Cold",
        "Cold",
        "Cold",
        "Off",
        "Off",
        "Off",
        "Off",
        "Hot",
        "Hot",
        "Hot",
        "Hot",
        "Cold",
        "Cold",
        "Cold",
        "Cold",
        "Off",
        "Off",
        "Off",
        "Off"
    ],
    "value" : [
        "200",
        "201",
        "200",
        "200",
        "140",
        "130",
        "140",
        "130",
        "90",
        "91",
        "92",
        "93",
        "200",
        "201",
        "200",
        "200",
        "140",
        "130",
        "140",
        "130",
        "90",
        "91",
        "92",
        "93",
        "200",
        "201",
        "200",
        "200",
        "140",
        "130",
        "140",
        "130",
        "90",
        "91",
        "92",
        "93"
    ]
})
```

The output should be in the following format

| Class | Hot-Start Time | Hot-End Time | Hot-Avg Value | Cold-Start Time | Cold-End Time | Cold-Avg Value | Off-Start Time | Off-End Time | Off-Avg Value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 2 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 3 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |

I have tried using the agg method on groupby as shown below

```
dfx["time"] = pd.to_datetime(dfx["time"])
dfx.groupby(["class", "mode"]).agg(
    {
        "time": ["min", "max"],
        "value": "mean"
    }
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Convert column `value` to numeric and `mode` to ordered [`Categorical`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Categorical.html) for correct ordering, then aggregate by [`DataFrame.unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html) and [`DataFrame.sort_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_index.html), last flatten `MultiIndex in columns`:

```
dfx['value'] = dfx['value'].astype(int)

dfx["time"] = pd.to_datetime(dfx["time"])

dfx["mode"] = pd.Categorical(dfx["mode"], ordered=True, categories=dfx['mode'].unique())

df = dfx.groupby(["class", "mode"]).agg(**{'Start Time':('time','min'),
                                           'End Time':('time','max'),
                                           'Avg Value':('value','mean')}

).unstack().sort_index(axis=1, level=1, sort_remaining=False)

df.columns = df.columns.map(lambda x: f'{x[1]} {x[0]}')
df = df.reset_index()
print (df)
  class      Hot Start Time        Hot End Time  Hot Avg Value  \
0     1 2022-10-01 10:33:31 2022-10-01 10:33:34         200.25   
1     2 2022-10-01 10:33:43 2022-10-01 10:33:46         200.25   
2     3 2022-10-01 10:33:55 2022-10-01 10:33:58         200.25   

      Cold Start Time       Cold End Time  Cold Avg Value      Off Start Time  \
0 2022-10-01 10:33:35 2022-10-01 10:33:38           135.0 2022-10-01 10:33:39   
1 2022-10-01 10:33:47 2022-10-01 10:33:50           135.0 2022-10-01 10:33:51   
2 2022-10-01 10:33:59 2022-10-01 10:34:02           135.0 2022-10-01 10:34:03   

         Off End Time  Off Avg Value  
0 2022-10-01 10:33:42           91.5  
1 2022-10-01 10:33:54           91.5  
2 2022-10-01 10:34:06           91.5
```